# How to wrap text around a subfigure?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, wrapfigure

I would like to align 3 subfigures vertically (all on top of each other), and then have these on the right side of the page with text wrapping around them. I know how to use wrapfig for a single figure and subcaption and subfigure to get the 3 vertical figures, but I can't seem to put the them together.

Here is what I currently have for the subfigure alignment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,float,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}

some text

\begin{figure}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centering\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:5a}\par\vfill
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:5b}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:5c}
\end{minipage}
\caption{subfigure}\label{fig:5}
\end{figure}

some text 
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help figure out a way to wrap the text around this figure environment? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide a complete example. How is `\some` defined? You at least need to end the document and provide sufficient text for wrapping. (Maybe that's what the `\some` is intended to do? Use e.g. `example-image-a` in place of `image1` etc. (there's `-b` and `-c` for `2` and `3`). Consider using `kantlipsum` or `lipsum` for the text.

Comment: I assume `letterhead` should be `letterpaper`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you like to have something  like this:

[image]

For this you need to use `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterhead]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,float,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:5a}\par\vfill
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:5b}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image3}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{fig:5c}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Figure}\label{fig:5}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Note: we haven't your original picture, so in the future similar cases please use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in your preamble :)

**Edit:**
code is now slightly changed (added is `minipage`) according to your wish expressed in comment below

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for this simple fix, and in the future I will add filler text to my question so it is easier to understand.

Comment: Actually, is there anyway I can change the bottom capture to label the whole entire figure instead of another subfigure? So the three images would be (a), (b), and (c), but instead of (d) at the bottom it would be Figure 5 to represent all of the figures?

Comment: @K.Schneider, see edited answer.

Comment: How about side-by-side?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian, please elaborate your comment. or better, if you have new question, ask it as question, not as comment.

Comment: I got it via doing two minipage environments instead of the one shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands without using the `figure` enviroment:

`\wrapr{<text vertical adjustment>}{<number of lines>}{<image width>}{<text vertical adjustment>}{image}{text}`

for placing the image on the right side or

`\wrapl{<text vertical adjustment>}{<number of lines>}{<image width>}{<text vertical adjustment>}{image}{text}`

for the left side of the document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterhead]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,float,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages,lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig,tikz}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption, subcaption}


\newenvironment{WrapText1}[3][r]
{\wrapfigure[#2]{#1}{#3}}
{\endwrapfigure}
\newenvironment{WrapText2}[3][l]
{\wrapfigure[#2]{#1}{#3}}
{\endwrapfigure}
\newcommand{\wrapr}[6]{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\mbox{}\\
\vspace{#1}
\begin{WrapText1}{#2}{#3}
\vspace{#4}#5\end{WrapText1}#6
\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\wrapl}[6]{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\mbox{}\\
\vspace{#1}
\begin{WrapText2}{#2}{#3}
\vspace{#4}#5\end{WrapText2}#6
\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
\wrapr{-5mm}{24}{4cm}{-5mm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-2,2.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:5a}\par\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-2,2.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:5b}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-2,2.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:5c}}
{\lipsum[1-3]}
\newpage
\wrapl{-5mm}{24}{4cm}{-5mm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-2,2.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:4a}\par\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-2,2.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:4b}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-2,2.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}
\label{fig:4c}}
{\lipsum[1-3]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]