# How to wrap text around part of a figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I am looking for wrapping some text around part of a figure in the following way:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aenean quis mi ut elit interdum imperdiet quis non ante.
+---------------------------+ +-------------------------+
|                           | |                         |
|                           | |                         |
|                           | |                         |
+---------------------------+ +-------------------------|
      (a) subfigure a              (b) subfigure b
                              +------------------------+
Sed imperdiet, sapien quis    |                        |
viverra rhoncus, tellus dui   |                        |
dictum nisl, at porta purus   |                        |
ipsum ac turpis. Fusce auctor |         FIGURE         |
ullamcorper adipiscing. Nunc  |          HERE          |
non quam ac orci egestas con- |                        |
sequat ut eget quam. Cras     +------------------------+
blandit condimentum ornare.         (c) subfigure c
Curabitur aliquam, nulla sit 
amet iaculis tristique, mi        Figure 1: demo
nulla auctor magna, sit amet imperdiet ante arcu a libero.
```

The example here [How to wrap text around a subfigure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383791/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-subfigure)
has it only for equal-sized subfigures (which, I usually do simply by putting subfloat in my wrapfigure). Is there any way to do what I am suggesting. I am on Fedora 29 which has the texlive distribution. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers.

The suggestion given works, but not for the subfig package (which uses subfloat that I thought was recommended over subfigure.)

Here is the example text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim,subfig}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering\ContinuedFloat*
\mbox{  \subfloat[]{\label{a}\includegraphics[draft,width=0.5\textwidth]{foo.png}}
  \subfloat[]{\label{b}\includegraphics[draft,width=0.5\textwidth]{foo.png}}}
\end{figure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}\centering\ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[]{\label{c}\includegraphics[draft,width=0.5\textwidth]{foo.png}}
  \caption{Demo}
  \label{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The counter deprecates every time ContinuedFloats in used.

[image]

I could perhaps add to the figure counter everytime continuedFloats is used but that does not seem kosher to me. I like clean solutions if available.

Comment: Regarding a comparison of the `subfig` package (used in your question)  and the `subcaption` package (used in the answer), see for example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13778/134144

Comment: This link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144782/subfigure-and-subfig-packages-deprecated says that subfigure is deprecated, hence I switched to subfig. Is that not true? The remainder of my document uses subfloat so this would be painful.

Comment: There are three different packages, `subfigure`, subfig` and `subcaption`. The first of them is deprecated. (The second one also introduces an environment called `subfigure`).

Comment: I thought that subfig introduces subfloat. Did not realize that it also did subfigure, but that does not address my question of the counter changing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered making use of `\ContinuedFloat` from the caption package (without defining a different label format for continued floats)?

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering\ContinuedFloat*
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[draft]{foo.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[draft]{foo.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{b}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}\centering\ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
      \includegraphics[draft]{foo.png}
      \caption{}
      \label{c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Demo}
    \label{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: continued_float_example]

More info on `\ContinuedFloat` in the LaTeX Wikibook: [8 Figures in multiple parts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures_in_multiple_parts).

Edit: User wants a working example using the subfig package.

The problem with your current example is that the first figure environment has no caption. The `\phantomcaption` command may be used to create a hidden caption which should clear up your issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
  % \ContinuedFloat* % Remove this.
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[draft]{foo.png}}
  \qquad
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[draft]{foo.png}}
  \phantomcaption
\end{figure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat\centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[draft]{foo.png}}
    \caption{Demo}
    \label{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

(also, remove the `\ContinuedFloat*` in the figure environment - it appears subfig does not use this - see section 2.2.3 of the subfig documentation).

Relevant 8 year old question: [numbering - ContinuedFloat, and Subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/continuedfloat-and-subfloat)

Comment: Very interesting: I had no idea of this approach. This is a cool answer. I will wait to see if there are better answers before checking, but this does address my problem.

Comment: I have added your answer among my favorites.

Comment: Very possible that there are - I've never used wrapfig before as doing so seems likely to lead to formatting woes. If you have problems with ContinuedFloat you could try manually set the (sub)figure number in the wrapped figure.

Comment: Yes, indeed, wrapfig is very finicky.

Comment: Counter drops every time ContiuedFloat is used with subfig package. See example.

Comment: See edit (output is unchanged)

Comment: Thanks! Works right. One issue that I do not like is the amount of whitespace between the figures (b) and (c). Any suggestions on how to reduce that?

Comment: Simply put, for example, \vspace{1cm} or \vspace{-1cm} in the wrapfigure environment immediately before the subfloat call (I've just checked this works as expected).